# Symfony - exclude specific route from security path

Tags: php, regex, symfony, yaml

In my **security.yaml** file I have:

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

But I have defined one more route: `api/doc` and `api/doc.json` which I want to exclude from this specific group like:

```
- { path: ^/api/doc, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

and I want to exclude just for this specific path but not from all `api/` extensions.

Do I need to put this endpoint above first one or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the version of Symfony you are using but the same applies for most of versions.

In the documentation states the following:

> For each incoming request, Symfony checks each access_control entry to find one that matches the current request. As soon as it finds a matching access_control entry, it stops - only the first matching access_control is used to enforce access.

So, this means that you should put first the paths that need the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role. This way, you only allow non authenticated sessions first an then check for your custom roles.

For example:

```
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/doc, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And your controller definition should be more or less like this:

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController
{
    /** @Route(name="api_doc", path="api/doc") */
    public function apiDoc()
    {
        return new Response('This is public');
    }
    
    /** @Route(name="api", path="api") */
    public function api()
    {
        return new Response('This is private');
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for replay. It's Symfony 5. :) I did it like this and I can see while accessing this endpoint that authentication is still required.  @WilliamsA.

Comment: Try with `PUBLIC_ACCESS` instead of `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` if using `Symfony 5` with the new authentification system from **Symfony 5.3**

Comment: @bjhonna If you're testing this on your local environment make sure you clear the Symfony cache after modifying the access_control because sometimes this causes the rules aren't updated properly. However, also make sure you are not doing some role verification inside the controller. Also, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users as the user above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and william's proposed solution wasn't working for me aswell, solved it adding to security.yaml file the following lines of code:

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            anonymous: true
```

My application use use symfony 5.4 and php 8.1